# chkdsk on a Windows Server 2008 R2 C: drive

Tags: windows, chkdsk

I'm trying to run a custom backup on my old Win Server 2008, I want to replace the C:\ hard drive.  I run the backup and select "Different Options" then "Custom" and then I select "Bare Metal" and it auto picks:

```
Bare Metal Recovery

System State

System Reserved

Local Disk C:
```

I have a second drive in there that I'll reattach once I get a new C:\ Drive in there.
The backup runs but it ends with two errors in the items list:

```
System Reserved          Completed.

C:                       Backup completed with warnings.

Bare metal recovery      Backup failed to complete.

System state             Completed.
```

In the errors tab it says:

```
4096 bytes could not be read due to the presence of bad clusters on your hard disk, and so have not been backed up.  Run CHKDSK /R on the hard disk, and then retry the backup.
```

Whats the best or recommended way to run the `CHKDSK /R`?   Just open CMD and run the command and have it scan on the next reboot?   I can't lose the drive until I get a decent backup...  I have the C:\ contents but it's also a backup DC in my office.

Answer (score 3):

`Whats the best or recommended way to run the CHKDSK /R ? Just open CMD and run the command and have it scan on the next reboot?`

Yes.